# Is all traffic within a network send to all hosts?

Tags: networking, routes

I am studying routing tables. Say you have the following line in a routing table

`Destination     Gateway         Genmask
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0`

This would mean that there is no gateway for local traffic on the network and some resoures write that all the traffic on a local network is send to all hosts on the network. This raises two question:

1. Isn't it a security risk that every host receives all traffic, even though it is not intended for that host.
2. Does it slow the network when every packet is send to all hosts over either cables or wifi even though it is intended for only 1 host?

Answer (score 0):

> Is all traffic within a network send to all hosts?

No. Traffic sent from a host to another host in the same network is sent via layer-2, not layer-3. That means that traffic from hosts in an IP network are sent to other hosts in the same network via the layer-2, e.g. ethernet, network.

There is a protocol called ARP (Address *Resolution* Protocol) that is used to resolve layer-3 (IP) to layer-2 (MAC) addresses.

A host sending something to another host will mask both the source and destination layer-3 addresses with the configured host network mask. If the results are the same, it will use ARP to address the layer-2 frame with the destination host MAC address, otherwise it will use ARP to address the frame with the layer-2 address of its configured gateway.

If there is no configured gateway, the host *should* drop the traffic between layer-3 and layer-2.

A host will drop any traffic not sent its MAC addresses, the broadcast address, or any multicast address for which it is not subscribed.